# can't change outerHTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, outerhtml

I have this HTML template on a page:

```
<div id="bid_wrapper_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]">
    <div class="form_item_block" id="bid_wrapper_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]">
        <div id="bid_delete_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]"><img src="/images/icons/cross.png"></div>
        <div id="bid_label_wrapper_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]">Bid #1</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="bid_summary" id="bid_summary_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]"></div>
        <div><input name="bid_price" id="bid_price_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to strip out the _[[template]] text, and also replace the [[bid_id]] with a number. I tried this:

```
var bid_template = document.getElementById('bid_wrapper_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]').cloneNode(true) 
var new_bid_id = 2

var new_oh = bid_template.outerHTML

new_oh = new_oh.replace(/_\[\[template\]\]/g, '')
new_oh = new_oh.replace(/\[\[bid_id\]\]/g, new_bid_id)
```

At this point if I console.log new_oh, it is exactly what I want - everything is replaced correctly. However the next lines...

```
var new_bid = document.createElement('div')
new_bid.outerHTML = new_oh
```

Nothing happens here when I try to set the outerHTML. It does work if I set the innerHTML, but I would prefer to set the outerHTML. I don't get any error messages, and I can't figure out why it's not setting the outerHTML.

Comment: Simply append it to an element on the page *before* using `.outerHTML`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assuming the error has occurred : that 'outerHTML' property on 'Element', so element has no parent node.

**if you want to create it with new `div`, then :**

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = output;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

**if not : then try this**

```js
var bid_template = document.getElementById('bid_wrapper_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]').cloneNode(true);
var new_bid_id = 2;
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var new_oh = bid_template.outerHTML;


var output = new_oh.replace(/_\[\[template\]\]/g, '');
output = output.replace(/\[\[bid_id\]\]/g, new_bid_id);

parent.innerHTML = output;
alert(output)
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="bid_wrapper_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]">
    <div class="form_item_block" id="bid_wrapper_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]">
      <div id="bid_delete_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]">
        <img src="/images/icons/cross.png">
      </div>
      <div id="bid_label_wrapper_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]">Bid #1</div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="bid_summary" id="bid_summary_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input name="bid_price" id="bid_price_[[bid_id]]_[[template]]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to insert or append the new_bid div to the document first, then reset its outerHTML.