# Why with forEach is does not work but with for loop it does? Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Can someone explain me why with a for loop it works and with a forEach it does not. I thought we could simply swap for with forEach with no problems.

It works! FOR LOOP

```
const logoPics = document.querySelectorAll('.logo__pic, .home__pic');

logoPics.forEach(logoPic => {
    let logoPicChildren = logoPic.children;
    for (let i = 0; i < logoPicChildren.length; i++) {
      logoPicChildren[i].outerHTML = logoPicChildren[i].outerHTML.replace(/logo-official/g,'logo-official-light');
      logoPicChildren[i].outerHTML = logoPicChildren[i].outerHTML.replace(/logo-alternative/g,'logo-alternative-light');
      logoPicChildren[i].outerHTML = logoPicChildren[i].outerHTML.replace(/logo-transparent/g,'logo-transparent-light');
    }
  });
```

It changes only "logo official". FOREACH

```
 const logoPics = document.querySelectorAll('.logo__pic, .home__pic');

  logoPics.forEach(logoPic => {
    let logoPicChildren = Array.from(logoPic.children);
    logoPicChildren.forEach(logoPicChild => {
      logoPicChild.outerHTML = logoPicChild.outerHTML.replace(/logo-official/g,'logo-official-light');
      logoPicChild.outerHTML = logoPicChild.outerHTML.replace(/logo-alternative/g,'logo-alternative-light');
      logoPicChild.outerHTML = logoPicChild.outerHTML.replace(/logo-transparent/g,'logo-transparent-light');
    })
  });
```

Comment: what is `logoPics`?

Comment: would be nice if you could provide a reproducable example (with logoPics defined)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't change outerHTML with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190395/cant-change-outerhtml-with-javascript)

Comment: Sorry I forgot part of the code:

const logoPics = document.querySelectorAll('.logo__pic, .home__pic');